# How can I remove a £ symbol from an array object and save it?

Tags: java, regex

I'm coding a basic chatbot for a University project. I'm up to a point where the user must set a budget by entering an amount. At the moment, the program is able to search for a number in the user's message and save it correctly. However, when a £ sign is prefixed to it, it can't save as an integer due to having the pound sign in the message.

This is my code:

```
//Scan the user message for a budget amount and save it.
    for (int budgetcount = 0; budgetcount < words.length; budgetcount++) 
    {
        if (words[budgetcount].matches(".*\\d+.*"))
        {
            if (words[budgetcount].matches("\\u00A3."))
            {
                words[budgetcount].replace("\u00A3", "");
                System.out.println("Tried to replace a pound sign");
                ResponsesDAO.budget = Integer.parseInt(words[budgetcount]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Can't find a pound sign here.");
            }
        }
```

I have previously tried .contains(), and other ways of indicating that it is a pound sign that I want to remove but I still get the "Can't find a pound sign here." print out.

If anybody can offer advice or correct my code I would appreciate it greatly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(words[budgetcount].matches("\\u00A3."))` Should use only 1 backslash. And this will match a 2 characters string only, and the first one would be your pound sign...

Comment: nice question... in times of brexit :D - therefore VOTED UP! sorry for this O/T, but even on stackoverflow there must be time for a short smile ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Strings` in JAVA are immutable. You are replacing but never assigning back the result to `words[budgetcount]`.

Change the following line in your code,

```
words[budgetcount] = words[budgetcount].replace("\u00A3", "");
```

Here is another way to do it by using `Character.isDigit(...)` to identify a digit and knitting a **digit-only** String which can later be parsed as an Integer,

**Code Snippet:**

```
private String removePoundSign(final String input) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            builder.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

**Input:**

```
System.out.println(removePoundSign("£12345"));
```

**Output:**

```
12345
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's sorted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `String.replaceAll` method.

Code snippet:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Code to remove non-digit number
        String budgetCount = "£34556734";
        String number=budgetCount.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");
        System.out.println(number);

        //Code to remove any specific characters
        String special = "$4351&2.";
        String result = special.replaceAll("[$+.^&]",""); // regex pattern
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
34556734
43512
```